# Regex to prevent the same character from appearing more than 3 times in a row

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, input

I want a javascript function that will prevent the same character from appearing more than 3 times in a row in an input field.  I know how to do this easily with 1 repeat. For example...

```js
function deleteit() {message.value=message.value.replace(/(.)\1/g,'')}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='message' onkeyup='deleteit()'>
```

If you enter the same character more than once here, the second gets deleted.  I want to allow up to 3 and delete on the 4th.  For example, "Yippy!!!" would be acceptable but typing "Yippy!!!!" would delete the 4th exclamation point.  I tried changing the regex to `/(..)\1/g`   That does work, but not quite. It's deleting 2 "Groups" of characters, so if I typed something like "YOYO" it would delete that. How can I change 4 or more of the same character to 3.

Comment: Use `/(.)\1{2}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
function deleteit() {message.value=message.value.replace(/(.)(\1{2})\1+/g,'$1$2')}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='message' onkeyup='deleteit()'>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1BdbT/2). *Details*:

- `(.)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): any char but a line break char
- `(\1{2})` - Capturing group 2 (`$2`): two chars that are equal to the one captured in Group 1
- `\1+` - one or more occurrences of the same char as the one captured in Group 1.

Or, alternatively:

```js
function deleteit() {message.value=message.value.replace(/((.)\2{2})\2+/g,'$1')}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='message' onkeyup='deleteit()'>
```

*Regex details*

- `((.)\2{2})` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to this group value):

  - `(.)` - Group 2: any char but a line break char
  - `\2{2}` - two occurrences of the Group 2 value
- `\2+` - one or more occurrences of Group 2 value

See the **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1BdbT/1)**.

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought this is what you're looking for:

Search pattern:

```
(.)(\1)\1+
```

Replacement pattern:

```
$1$2
```

https://regex101.com/r/tAFNUa/1